# Constraint: You cannot be a supporter of an NGO if you are below 18 years old

Tags: mysql, ddl

I have the following tables:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGvDW.png

Where can i enter this constraint to check if age is atleast 18? Kind of confusing

Comment: constraints exist on tables. If you show us the relevant table schema details it might help you get an answer

Comment: Please don't screenshot text and code. Please copy and paste it and use the formatting buttons at the top of the editor to clean it up. Please also include your table DDL, not just a list. This will likely just need a check constraint like `check(age>=18)` or something. Lastly, please read [how to ask a homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/2221001). It's brief, but will help you get answers here.

Comment: @JNevill apologies about that, I'm new here. Yes I was thinking about having the check age constraint, just uncertain which attribute to have it at?

Comment: `Supporter` contains `Birthday` column which can be checked with CHECK constraint.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a CHECK CONSTRAINT, but we have to hard-code the date because CURRENT_DATE is not allowed in a CHECK CONSTRAINT. Please note that check constraint only function on recents editions of mySQL.
If this approach is not what you are looking for the other possibility is a TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT. A trigger has the advantage of being able to check other rows and other table, which CONSTRAINTS cannot do.

> ```
> create table Supporter (
> name varchar(25), 
> email varchar(25), 
> phone varchar(25), 
> address varchar(25), 
> zip_code varchar(25),
> city varchar(25), 
> birthday date CHECK (birthday < '2004-03-17')
> ) ;
> ```

> ```
> insert into Supporter (name, birthday) values ('Andrew','2000-01-01');
> ```

> ```
> insert into Supporter (name, birthday) values ('Bernard','2010-01-01');
> ```
>
> ```
> Check constraint 'Supporter_chk_1' is violated.
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=81876626fdb79b3fd5137e3c1b7e4b07)*